# Google Analytics Link Tracking

Tags: hyperlink, google-analytics, tracking

OK, so I've set up a website where the content is split into modals that are hidden. There are links on the page that when clicked on, the relevant modal appears. I want to be able to track the links being clicked on so I can see what content is being viewed by users. Ideally I want the data to appear as fake pageviews. I know this used to be possible but not sure how to do it nowadays.

I can't seem to find any decent up to date documentation online for how to do this. Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the Analytics initialized for asynchrounous, just call

```
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'FAKE_URL']);
```

This should work and will not slow down your page load. You might want to consider using "events" rather than fake page views; it's also quite simple

```
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', "EVENT NAME", "PARAMETER"]);
```

See [Google's Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration) for more info.

Comment: Fantastic. However, I have tried this already. I have a feeling the CMS my company is using may be doing something to stop it working. Does the URL have to be the full URL or can it be relative?

Comment: I am using relative URLs and it works just fine. 

I suggest you look at the page created by the CMS (by doing "view source" in your browser) and checking manually that the GA initialization code runs there, including the initialization of the queue (`var _gaq = _gaq || [];`) and setting it for async operation (`ga.async = true;`). If it's missing, then that's your problem.

Comment: it does indeed seem to be missing. I'll give that a go cheers